# Automating docker using python

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

Hi I am working with docker quite extensively and now also using docker-compose.

This is proving to be very useful but I am finding that I am re-creating a lot of my services with various subtle config changes in various projects.

So is there a way to automate docker compose. Can I use a python SDK to build the compose file? My goal is build the docker-compose file using python code.

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: I think using templates/template engines will work. Later populate the templates using the service related component templates. Hence creating full schema.

Comment: try ansible templates ( just google it, you will find a lot of links how to do it)